# Method for runtime comparison of two programs' objects

Tags: debugging, language-agnostic, stack-trace, data-tracing

I am working through a particular type of code testing that is rather nettlesome and could be automated, yet I'm not sure of the best practices.  Before describing the problem, I want to make clear that I'm looking for the appropriate terminology and concepts, so that I can read more about how to implement it.  Suggestions on best practices are welcome, certainly, but my goal is specific: what is this kind of approach called?

In the simplest case, I have two programs that take in a bunch of data, produce a variety of intermediate objects, and then return a final result.  When tested end-to-end, the final results differ, hence the need to find out where the differences occur.  Unfortunately, even intermediate results may differ, but not always in a significant way (i.e. some discrepancies are tolerable).  The final wrinkle is that intermediate objects may not necessarily have the same names between the two programs, and the two sets of intermediate objects may not fully overlap (e.g. one program may have more intermediate objects than the other).  Thus, I can't assume there is a one-to-one relationship between the objects created in the two programs.

The approach that I'm thinking of taking to automate this comparison of objects is as follows (it's roughly inspired by frequency counts in text corpora):

1. For each program, A and B: create a list of the objects created throughout execution, which may be indexed in a very simple manner, such as a001, a002, a003, a004, ... and similarly for B (b001, ...).
2. Let Na = # of unique object names encountered in A, similarly for Nb and # of objects in B.
3. Create two tables, TableA and TableB, with Na and Nb columns, respectively.  Entries will record a value for each object at each trigger (i.e. for each row, defined next).
4. For each assignment in A, the simplest approach is to capture the hash value of all of the Na items; of course, one can use LOCF (last observation carried forward) for those items that don't change, and any as-yet unobserved objects are simply given a NULL entry.  Repeat this for B.
5. Match entries in TableA and TableB via their hash values.  Ideally, objects will arrive into the "vocabulary" in approximately the same order, so that order and hash value will allow one to identify the sequences of values.
6. Find discrepancies in the objects between A and B based on when the sequences of hash values diverge for any objects with divergent sequences.

Now, this is a simple approach and could work wonderfully if the data were simple, atomic, and not susceptible to numerical precision issues.  However, I believe that numerical precision may cause hash values to diverge, though the impact is insignificant if the discrepancies are approximately at the machine tolerance level.

First: What is a name for such types of testing methods and concepts?  An answer need not necessarily be the method above, but reflects the class of methods for comparing objects from two (or more) different programs.

Second: What are standard methods exist for what I describe in steps 3 and 4?  For instance, the "value" need not only be a hash: one might also store the sizes of the objects - after all, two objects cannot be the same if they are massively different in size.

In practice, I tend to compare a small number of items, but I suspect that when automated this need not involve a lot of input from the user.

---

Edit 1: [This paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.117.5860&rep=rep1&type=pdf) is related in terms of comparing the execution traces; it mentions "code comparison", which is related to my interest, though I'm concerned with the data (i.e. objects) than with the actual code that produces the objects.  I've just skimmed it, but will review it more carefully for methodology.  More importantly, this suggests that comparing code traces may be extended to comparing data traces.  [This paper](http://www.ieee-security.org/TC/SP2011/PAPERS/2011/paper022.pdf) analyzes some comparisons of code traces, albeit in a wholly unrelated area of security testing.

Perhaps data-tracing and stack-trace methods are related.  Checkpointing is slightly related, but its typical use (i.e. saving all of the state) is overkill.

Edit 2: Other related concepts include [differential program analysis](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/pubs/woda.pdf) and monitoring of remote systems (e.g. space probes) where one attempts to reproduce the calculations using a local implementation, usually a clone (think of a HAL-9000 compared to its earth-bound clones).  I've looked down the routes of unit testing, reverse engineering, various kinds of forensics, and whatnot.  In the development phase, one could ensure agreement with unit tests, but this doesn't seem to be useful for instrumented analyses.  For reverse engineering, the goal can be code & data agreement, but methods for assessing fidelity of re-engineered code don't seem particularly easy to find.  Forensics on a per-program basis are very easily found, but comparisons between programs don't seem to be that common.

Answer (score 0):

(Making this answer community wiki, because dataflow programming and reactive programming are not my areas of expertise.)

The area of data flow programming appears to be related, and thus debugging of data flow programs may be helpful.  [This paper from 1981](http://csg.csail.mit.edu/pubs/memos/Memo-219/Memo-219.pdf) gives several useful high level ideas.  Although it's hard to translate these to immediately applicable code, it does suggest a method I'd overlooked: when approaching a program as a dataflow, one can either statically or dynamically identify where changes in input values cause changes in other values in the intermediate processing or in the output (not just changes in execution, if one were to examine control flow).

Although dataflow programming is often related to parallel or distributed computing, it seems to dovetail with [Reactive Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming), which is how the monitoring of objects (e.g. the hashing) can be implemented.

This answer is far from adequate, hence the CW tag, as it doesn't really name the debugging method that I described.  Perhaps this is a form of debugging for the reactive programming paradigm.

[Also note: although this answer is CW, if anyone has a far better answer in relation to dataflow or reactive programming, please feel free to post a separate answer and I will remove this one.]

---

Note 1: Henrik Nilsson and Peter Fritzson [have a number of papers](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~nhn/papers.html) on debugging for lazy functional languages, which are somewhat related: the debugging goal is to assess values, not the execution of code.  [This paper](ftp://ftp.ida.liu.se/pub/labs/pelab/papers/aadebug93ladb.ps.gz) seems to have several good ideas, and their work partially inspired [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.37.4044&rep=rep1&type=ps) on a debugger for a reactive programming language called Lustre.  These references don't answer the original question, but may be of interest to anyone facing this same challenge, albeit in a different programming context.